# How to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging via APNs using an already registered bundle identifier?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

The docs for setting up [FCM via APNs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/) state that you should copy the bundle identifier from your application (under the "Registering an App Identifier") section, but when I do that I get the following error when trying to register my new app id:

> An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value
>
> An App ID with Identifier '<my app id copied from xcode>' is not
> available. Please enter a different string.

The error message does make sense because that app id *is* already taken (by my app).

Are the Firebase docs wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check the followings.

1. make sure if you have already checked an option for push notification on app store. go to developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list, choose your identifier in the list.
   [image]
2. open your project in Xcode. and check like the below screenshot
   [image]

Comment: Gah, okay I simply don't need a new app ID... Already have Push Notifications enabled. I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/8585) to the flutterfire docs to clarify. Thanks!